# Problemas ao serializar objeto para XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialização

Após serializar para XML um objeto algumas propriedades desaparecem.
Estes objetos foram gerados automaticamente com o add references services
e não possuem o [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]

porém não estão aparecendo no XML apos o objeto ser serializado.

Alguem ja passou por esse problema? alguma ideia de como resolver?

O Fonte que estou usando para este teste está no git https://github.com/ntfrigo/WinBetha2

[image: Debuggando o processo]

Answer (score 0):

Descobri como resolver o problema, então vou deixar documentado para outros que possam precisar.

Todas as propriedades que possuam o "Specified" devem ser definidas com **true** para que o mesmo possa ser serializado e constar no XML, caso contrario serão removidos.

As propriedades que não contem o "Specified" sempre irão constar no XML.